# How can I have a php script call a perl script that requires a parameter?

Tags: php, perl

I have a php script that allows people to upload files to a server, and I have a perl script to convert the filetype to something more useful for data extraction. The php script saves the name of the uploaded file as $filename . In order to run, the converting script needs to be passed the name of the file to be converted. I was able to call a test script and pass it the name of the uploaded file in the following way

```
exec("/usr/bin/perl /full/path/to/mytestscript.pl $filename");
```

This test script executed all of the commands that I needed it to. However, this did not work with my converting script. The code to keep the variable is the same in both the test script and the converting script.

I can run the converting perl script fine from the terminal, but I want to run it from the php script. I run the converting perl script from the terminal by navigating to the directory holding both the file to be converted and the converting perl script.

```
perl my_converting_script.pl file_to_convert.TCX
```

Any advice on how to have the converting script run from the php script instead of the terminal would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Who knows, maybe you're missing full path to your `file_to_convert.TCX`

Comment: Maybe your file resides outside the server `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Thanks mpapec that was the exact problem!